# Linear search returning not found when it should be returning subscript number

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, search

I'm working on a homework assignment for Java, where a program is supposed to read in 10 numbers from the user, then ask for a number to search. It sorts the numbers (ascending) and performs a linear search on the array, then should either return the subscript it was found at or a message saying not found.

My code is giving me the "not found" response even when the subscript should be returned. Can you take a look at my code? I've tried altering my if statement and it didn't help. I've used the book examples of the search and sort methods as closely as I could (feel free to point out errors).

Here is the code.

```
package program11;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArraySearch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] arrayBuild = new double[10];
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayBuild.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter a number.");
            arrayBuild[i] = input.nextDouble();
        }

        System.out.print("Enter a number to search for ");
        int objective = input.nextInt();

        linearCheck(arrayBuild, objective);

        if ((objective >= 0) && (objective < arrayBuild.length)) {
            System.out.println("Found at index: " + objective);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not Found");
        }
    }

    public static void arraySort(double[] arrayBuild) {
        for (int i = 1; i < arrayBuild.length; i++) {
            double currentPoint = arrayBuild[i];
            int r;
            for (r = i - 1; r >= 0 && arrayBuild[r] > currentPoint; r--) {
                arrayBuild[r + 1] = arrayBuild[r];
            }
            arrayBuild[r + 1] = currentPoint;
        }
    }

    public static double linearCheck(double[] arrayBuild, int objective) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayBuild.length; i++) {
            if (objective == arrayBuild[i])
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

}
```

---

EDIT- new code. It's all complete now, except when I enter a number that is not in the array I get a negative result. For example, entering 10 8 7 6 5 3 5 3 5 3 5 6 and searching for 11 gives me the result of -1 for the linear search and -11 for the binary search. I took your advice as well as I could. What am I missing now?

```
package program11;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class ArraySearch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] arrayBuild = new double[10];
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int reply = 2;

for (int i = 0; i < arrayBuild.length; i++) {
    System.out.print("Enter a number.");
    arrayBuild[i] = input.nextDouble();
        }
while (reply != 1) {
        System.out.print("Enter a number to search for ");
        double objective = input.nextDouble();

arraySort(arrayBuild);
        double linearResult = linearCheck(arrayBuild, objective);

if (objective >= 0) {
        System.out.println("Linear search found at index: " + linearResult);
                }
else {
        System.out.println("Not Found (linear)");
        }
        double binaryResult = binaryCheck(arrayBuild, objective);

if (objective >= 0) {
System.out.println("Binary search found at index: " + binaryResult);
                }
else {
     System.out.println("Not Found (binary)");
        }
reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Continue?"); 
    }
}

public static void arraySort(double[] arrayBuild) {
    for (int i = 1; i < arrayBuild.length; i++) {
        double currentPoint = arrayBuild[i];
        int r;
        for (r = i - 1; r >= 0 && arrayBuild[r] > currentPoint; r--) {
            arrayBuild[r + 1] = arrayBuild[r];
        }
        arrayBuild[r + 1] = currentPoint;
    }
    }

public static double linearCheck(double[] arrayBuild, double objective) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayBuild.length; i++) {
        if (objective == arrayBuild[i])
            return i;
    }
return -1;
    }
public static double binaryCheck(double[] arrayBuild, double objective) {
    int low = 0;
    int high = arrayBuild.length - 1;

    while (high >= low) {
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;
        if (objective < arrayBuild[mid])
            high = mid - 1;
        else if (objective == arrayBuild[mid])
            return mid;
        else
        low = mid + 1;
    }
return -low - 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not the behavior I see. Where do you sort the array?

Comment: I sort the array under the arraySort method. It's working for you? If I enter 10 numbers, with 1 being included, and i choose 1 as my search objective, I get the not found response. =/

Comment: @Chris I didn't say it worked; it doesn't--but that's a simple output error. Also, why is `objective` an `int`, but the array entries `double`?

Comment: @user1082706 Buuuuut... where do you *call* `arraySort`? It's not going to call itself. Also, what do you output for "found"/"not found"?

Comment: I don't see *the* problem, but: (1) nothing never calls `arraySort`, so you're not actually sorting the array; (2) you shouldn't generally be doing `==` comparisons on `double`s, since they don't store exact values; and (3) it's bizarre that your `linearCheck` is searching an array of `double`s for an `int`. But I don't think any of those is *the* problem. :-/

Comment: ahhh thank you and thank you i understand what you're saying now. and i was calling it as an int because i was confused and thought it should be using an integer type with the subscript number.

Comment: @user1082706 You *should* use an int as the array index (subscript)--that much is right :)

Comment: ahh gotcha, figured it out. now working on getting it to return the actual subscript and not the number of the subscript.. (fixed)

Comment: you don't want to use if (objective >= 0) you should be using the result of the search like this if (linearResult >= 0) and if (binaryResult >= 0)

Comment: i fixed it by adding the part i cut out earlier saying "if (objective >= 0 && objective <= arrayBuild.length) {" and it worked fine. is that acceptable? it's been turned in already (your way does make more sense admittedly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly sure what is causing your problems, but I see a few issues with your code

1. If you want to be searching for Ints then I would also make `arrayBuild` of type int as well. Or you could search for doubles by changing the type of `objective` to double and getting the user to input a double
2. When you call `linearCheck` you are not storing the result anywhere, you should assign it to a variable

   ```
   double foundLocation = linearCheck(arrayBuild, objective);
   ```
3. Your if statement doesn't make much sense, you ought to be using the returned value of `linearCheck` as follows

   ```
   if (foundLocation >= 0) {
       System.out.println("Found at index: " + foundLocation);
   } else {
       System.out.println("Not Found");
   }
   ```
4. You are not calling `arraySort` anywhere in your main

Comment: thank you! that helps, i figured it out. the only problem now is that it's returning the number and i should be getting the subscript. i'll mess with it some more.

Answer (score 1):

You are never saving the value of your search. Your objective isn't the same as your result. Here's the code change I would make:

```
    int result = linearCheck(arrayBuild, objective);

    if ((result >= 0) && (result < arrayBuild.length)) {
        System.out.println("Found at index: " + result);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not Found");
    }
```

This change requires you to make an int returned for your linear check routine.

this is in addition to make `objective` a double and not an integer.